# Chrome not showing mediaquery stuff correctly

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I have a page here, that I would like to have it so that the home page slider is at least hidden for now on the home page. It looks great on the mobile safari browser, but it doesn't show my div "primary_home" as hidden as it should in chrome, and I'm assuming the native mobile browser for a droid.

this is the page:
forloveofallthings.com/home

```
this is the css used that makes it look the way it should in safari:
#primary_home {
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0 !important;
float: right;
width: 320px;
margin-right: 0px;
display: none;
}
```

Can someone please take a looK?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about this mediaquery,

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
```

The stylesheet that's being served doesn't have the

```
display: none;
```

line.

Check that you've uploaded the stylesheet correctly, and clear any server-side caches.

Comment: Thanks I actually changed something on that slider though, but it STILL does not show up the same in the mobile chrome browser though.. And alternatively, if I try to make my browser small on my desktop it does not display the same as when I just view the home page on a mobile browser... any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: Can someone please check up on this for me?  Not sure what the issue might be.

Comment: Not sure I'll be able to help, but someone might be able to if you can give a little more detail.  Can you post some screen shots of what you're seeing and what you're expecting to see?

Comment: Figured this out.  Ended up just having to remove a div in the head section, which helped clear the cache.. then just start developing stuff in the 450 width media query instead of the 320.  Thanks